# Full page navigation slide in fade in fade out issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A full page navigation slides into into view when the user clicks on the `<a href="#slide-nav" class="slide-nav-trigger">` I'm using CSS to trigger the animations and jQuery for event delegation.

#### The issue

I'd like to have `slide-nav` fade in and fadeout instead of just having it flicking on and off when user toggles the `navigation-is-on` class to the `body`. I've been able to achieve the fading in effect (only on one click.) by animating the opacity of `slide-nav`

```
$(function(){
// assign click event to slide-nav-trigger
$('.slide-nav-trigger').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel the default action

    // when user clicks slide-nav-trigger toggleClass navigation-is-open to body
    $('body').toggleClass('navigation-is-open');

    var slideNav = $('.slide-nav');
    slideNav.animate({
        opacity:1 }, 2000, function(){});
    });
});
```

As you can see here I'm targeting the `slide-nav` and animating it's opacity so I get the fading in effect. This method is the only way that I seem to be able to achieve the effect that I'm after. I tried to use the `fadeIn` method but I cant seem to make it work.

Here's the link to 
[the codepen](http://codepen.io/kapena/pen/bVMgEW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need another function to run on "click" if body has class.  You can do it with just css as you're already triggering the class though:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdRaye

```
.slide-nav{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    background-color:#51585A;
        transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    .navigation-is-open & {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .slide-navigation-wrapper{
        // main navigation content here
        height:100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-scrolling:touch;
        // padds links over to the left
        padding:40px 5% 40px calc(5% + 80px);
        // Force Hard W acceleration webkit
        @include transition(translateZ(0));
        backface-visibility:hidden;
        // transform links on X axis -50% hidden off screen!
        @include transform(translateX(-50%));
        // transition the transformation
        @include transition(transform $animation-dur);
        // transition timing function makes the animation smooth
        @include transition-timing-function(cubic-bezier(.86,.01,.77,.78));
    }
    // adding navigation-is-open class and assigning our parent selector `slide-nav`

    // when slide-nav-trigger button is clicked on I toggle navigation-is-on to body of html

    .navigation-is-open & {
        visibility: visible;
        // transition visibility

        // slide-navigation-wrapper slides out when navigation-is-on is toggled to body
        .slide-navigation-wrapper{
            // transition translate on the X axis `0`
            @include transform(translateX(0));


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieved a similar solution for fading in and fading out the opacity of the `slide-nav` div with jQuery.

When user clicks on `slide-nav-trigger` the `navigation-is-open` class is toggled to the `body` element and the first evaluation in the `if` statement evaluates to `true` which then executes the fade in animation on `slide-nav`

```
// if body hasClass of navigation-is-open toggled on
if ($('body').hasClass('navigation-is-open')){
        // animate opacity on slide-nav from 0 to 1
        slideNav.animate({
            opacity:1 }, 2000, function(){});
        // if navigation-is-open is toggled off
       }
```

When the user clicks `slide-nav-trigger` for a second time it toggles off the class of `navigation-is-open` from the `body` which is then when the `if` statement evaluate's to `false` because I no longer have a class of `navigation-is-open` attached to the `body` element anymore. So I use the `else` statement now to animate the opacity from 1 to 0 on `slide-nav`

```
if ($('body').hasClass('navigation-is-open')){
    // animate opacity on slide-nav from 0 to 1
    slideNav.animate({
        opacity:1 }, 2000, function(){});
    // if navigation-is-open is toggled off
    } else {
        // animate opacity from 1 to 0
        slideNav.animate({
            opacity:0 },1000, function(){});
    }
```

Link to updated [Pen](http://codepen.io/kapena/pen/bVMgEW?editors=101)